# Does setting "Wireless Network mode" to "disabled" on Linksys Router really completely turn off Wifi?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have WRT54G Linksys router and don't want to have Wifi on 24/7 when I don't need it - for health concerns (less so for digital security). Is it sufficient to change the setting on the wireless web interface? Or am I better off unplugging power on the router? It does not seem to have on/off button.

Comment: What do you mean by "really turn it off".  How "off" do you need it? What have your tests shown?  IMO, If you're worried about health concerns from electronic devices, then unplugging them is always the best option. ;)

Comment: off = not transmitting any signals, in my naive understanding

Comment: What makes you believe it's still transmitting signals after you've set it to disabled?

Comment: nothing, except for paranoia:) I want to understand what that setting actually does, compared to unplugging. I do know that I can't access WIFI once I set it to "disabled", so I have good reason to believe it's working as expected - the question is to get  confirmation and better understanding.

Comment: Get a Wifi meter. :) If you've got a smart phone there's a few free apps that do a good job at WiFi signal detection.

Comment: thanks for suggestion - is there any particular app that you have in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does.

If you are further concerned - I can't remember whether it has removable aerials but if it does, remove them. Then even if the transmitter came on, there would be virtually no output at all.